# Android P FingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints replacement

Tags: android, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api

As of **Android P (API 28)** the `FingerprintManager` API was deprecated and Google suggests we should switch to `BiometricPrompt` API.

However `FingerprintManager` has a method named `hasEnrolledFingerprints` that we're currently using to display a prompt to the user right after he logs in with email / password where we ask him if he wants to use his fingerprint for future authentication (such as when the session expires).

`BiometricPrompt` API doesn't have a similar method, so this breaks our current UX and we're not sure how to address this.

I guess the alternative would be to simply encrypt the user's password without allowing him the option to manually "enroll", and simply use the `BiometricPrompt` API when his session expires, but we feel that the user should be informed and opt-in into this feature.

I did some digging trying to find out where I could ask such a question on Google's  feedback platform, but couldn't find where.

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: In the meanwhile I've created an issue here - https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112491966